# How do I override only the "top-level" operator in TLC?

Tags: tla+, tlc

I have two specs like this:

```
---- MODULE Spec ----
VARIABLE x

Init == x \in BOOLEAN

Next == x' = ~x
Spec == Init /\ [][Next]_x
====

---- MODULE MCSpec ----
EXTENDS Spec

MCInit == Init /\ x = FALSE \* Optimization

MCSpec == MCInit /\ [][Next]_x
====
```

It would be easier if I didn't have to define `MCSpec`, and could just add a module override to `MCSpec.cfg`:

```
CONSTANT
  Init <- MCInit
```

But this raises a recursion error, as `MCInit` calls `Init`, which is replaced by `MCInit`, which calls `Init`...

Is there a way to only replace the "Top-level" `Init` via an override?

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is not wanting to define `MCSpec`, instead of using `SPECIFICATION MCSpec` in your model file (.cfg) you can use:

```
INIT MCInit
NEXT Next
```